# -Parameters appear undefined-

Tags: node.js, geddy

I've followed the tutorial from [here](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial) (without scaffolding) and completed the app.

My question is: when I click on a created item and the list of parameters id diplayed, why are the title and status undefined. In the list of ITEMS they are correct, but when I click on one item, they appear undefined. Why is this happening?

List of items (left: title, right: status): http://s12.postimage.org/dt262qngd/items_list.png

List of params for an item: http://s23.postimage.org/n3p5yffqj/params.png

Thanks!

Comment: can you give more information from node server log?
or console?

Comment: the last lines of the console... http://s11.postimage.org/3te0r0s9f/console.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem... In the show.html.ejs file, instead of

```
<%= p + ': ' + params[p]; %>
```

I have to write

```
<%= p + ': ' + arithmetic_problem_type[p]; %>
```

and this has the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to connect to socket.io server. 
Add listen on your http server instance.

```
var io = socketio.listen(geddy.server);
```

See [this](https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/108). 
Authorization failure can also cause this problem. For authorization on socket.io requests, check [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing). 
Geddy can help adding local, Facebook, and Twitter authentication directly with `geedy auth`.

If you haven't used socket.io when creating geddy project, create project with this option

`geddy app -rt`

Comment: no...I didn't use that command...so if I want to see the parameters I must create the app in that way?

Comment: I have another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274596/display-only-some-of-the-parameters)...please take a look

Comment: I have created the app with **geddy app -rt test2**, the message about the socket doesn't appear in the console anymore, but still the params are undefined...I've also written **var io = socketio.listen(geddy.server);** in the **socket.io.js** file...

Comment: Don't modify any node package file (socket.io.js). You are supposed to change above line in app.js or file in which you create http server.

Comment: Make sure that you have installed package dependencies.